# SQL Server 2016 TDE versus Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server, msdtc

I am working in order to enrypt SQL Server 2016 DB Data files with TDE.

My questions:

- Is it possible for a non-encrypted database to access the encrypted one via linked server and vice versa?
- How does it work with distributed transactions between Encrypted and non-Enrypted databases?

Comment: Stripped the question for documentation, as that is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It is easy enough to find yourself using your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "T" in "TDE" stands for "transparent". Meaning "transparent to any clients". For all intents and purposes, once the database is decrypted and brought online, it acts as any other database. Specific to your question, linked server queries should work no differently nor should transactions (distributed or otherwise).